# Python Intro, if statements. Invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

Hello everyone im new here and new to python. Im working on some Python exercises I found online and am stuck on what I am doing wrong. Im trying to learn and teach myself about if and else statements. Here is my code.

```
weight = (float(input("How much does your suitcase weigh? "))
if weight > 50:
          print("There is a $25 fee for a luggage that heavy.")

print("Thank you for your buisness. ")

input()
```

I am getting an invalid syntax error after 50: and not sure why. Can anyone briefly explain what im doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first line, you're missing an end parentheses.

```
weight = (float(input("How much doees your suitcase weigh? ")))
if weight > 50 :
     print("There is a $25 fee for a luggage that heavy.")

print("Thank you for your buisness. ")

input()
```

Comment: Well that makes sense. That works and I understand where I messed up. Thank you!

Comment: @Matticus A tip: if you're getting an error on a line that looks fine, it usually means you missed a parenthesis on the line above. And accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and whoops didn't realize thats what the Check was for.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct...and you actually have extra parentheses.

This code also works:

```
weight = float(input("How much does your suitcase weigh? "))

if weight > 50:
    print("There is a $25 fee for a luggage that heavy.")

print("Thank you for your business")
```

Answer (score 0):

in any programming language you need to know about what you opened/closed parentheses.

```
weight = (float(input(
```

now you have three ( ( ( so at the end you need three parentheses too

```
weigh? ")))
```